# Set the initial value of state when I want to cross out text when checkbox is checked

Tags: reactjs

I'm beginner and I'm working on Todo app in "React". I made a class with text-decoration: line-through and I want to cross out text when checkbox checked. But I don't know what to set the initial value of the checked variable?

```
const Tasks = (props) => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const TaskChecked = (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked === true) {
      setChecked(true);
    } else if (event.target.checked === false) {
      setChecked(false);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="task_item">
      <ul>
        {props.tasks.map((task) => (
          <li>
            <div className="task_name">{task.title}</div>
            <button className="delete_btn">
              <FaTimesCircle className="delete_item" />
            </button>
            <button className="edit_btn">
              <FaEdit className="edit_item" />
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" id="taskCheck" onChange={TaskChecked} />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You're setting checked to false initially:
`const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);`
You aren't using the value of checked anywhere so far.
Where is the text you are planning to style?

Comment: Pleases share the css also, and where you wish to use the checked state.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize your state by using the `tasks` and add to them a checked property.
Doing this will allow you to check / uncheck only a specific element and conditionally add a style to it.
(I assumed that your `tasks` have a unique `id`).

```
const Tasks = (props) => {
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const tasksWithChecked = props.tasks.map((task) => {
        return { ...task, checked: false };
      });
      setTasks(tasksWithChecked);
    }, []);
  
    const TaskChecked = (event) => {
      // Update toggled task
      const updatedTask = tasks.find((task) => task.id === event.target.value);
      if (!updatedTask) return;
      updatedTask.checked = !updatedTask.checked;
      const otherTasks = tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== event.target.value);
      setTasks([...otherTasks, updatedTask]);
    };
  
    return (
      <div className='task_item'>
        <ul>
          {tasks.map((task) => (
            {/* Add unique key attribute to list item */}
            <li key={task.id}>
              <div
                {/* Apply custom class conditionally */}
                className={`task_name ${
                  task.checked ? '<your-custom-class-name' : ''
                }`}
              >
                {task.title}
              </div>
              <button className='delete_btn'>
                <FaTimesCircle className='delete_item' />
              </button>
              <button className='edit_btn'>
                <FaEdit className='edit_item' />
              </button>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                id='taskCheck'
                value={task.id}
                onChange={TaskChecked}
              />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  };
```